# Multiple file ordering in Nautilus file manager in general e per folder

Tags: nautilus

I'm looking for two things, both regarding nautilus file ordering.

(Premise: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 coming from dist-upgrade.)

**1**) I can't change it's behavior.
I tried with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'type'
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'name'
```

but I don't see any change.

I want the files appear in this order:

```
type_folder name_Gdd modified_may:15
type_folder name_Fdd modified_apr:10
type_folder name_Jdd modified_may:15
type_file   name_Gcc modified_may:15
type_file   name_Gff modified_may:22
type_file   name_Ggg modified_may:15
```

or, in words, order by type then by name and then by date.

---

**2**) ordering settings per folder (or rapidly changeable)

The ordering in **1** would be the default, but I would also like to have different settings for a specific folder.

Example: The folder "download" should be order by modification and by  name; in such a way whatever I download is the first in the folder.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After opening Nautilus, notice against Activities on the top bar an item called Files with a down arrow. Click on that and select Preferences.

[image]

From this point, you can select the options you require from the Views, Behavior, List Columns, and Search & Preview tabs.